# Call module on product-page with attribute value

Tags: magento-2.1, module, attributes, customize

I have developed a module and want to call this module on product-page with custom-attribute.

I want to call this module on specific product, `not on all products` so to do that i will create a custom attribute and put the code in attribute on product-edit-page.  That module display only on specific product.

How can I achieve this using magento standard?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @ Jai , As far as I know, a module's scope is available in the entire magento system and we can only control the calls to those particular modules, based on our entities. We cannot restrict a module available only to some specific product. What I would suggest is, create some attribute and, based on that attribute value for your specific product, trigger the functionality of your required module. You can do this through action controllers.

Comment: Thanks for your input and I think its possible the way I want it. I am trying to make it product specific by following proper magento standards.

Comment: Great, good luck.